# Remove one line in txt file ( NODE.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I make a text file "foo\nbar\nbas"

When i append coke(with adding \n), then the file will be "foo\nbar\nbas\ncoke"

I want to remove the foo.

Help me!

Comment: Multiple ways to do it, indexOf, Substring, arrays, etc

Comment: Read the file, find the first \n write back everything after it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fo your use case that you have provided, a simple answer is split on \n, remove the first item, add the new item to the end, and join the array to form your new string.

```
var parts = "foo\nbar\nbas".split("\n").slice(1);
parts.push("coke");
var updated = parts.join("\n");
```

Other option is to use indexOf to find the first occurrence of `\n` and substring to select the portion of the string, then it is a simple concatenation.

```
var str = "foo\nbar\nbas";
var position = str.indexOf("\n")+1;
var updated = str.substring(position) + "\ncoke";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple string manipulation if your task is not complicated by further constraints. Such is as follows:

```
var fileContents = "foo\nbar\nbas";

// Read Text File, in this case, I have set it.

fileContents = fileContents.replace("foo\n", "");

fileContents += "\ncoke";

// Write back to file
```